# How to combine two pandas dataframes on two different columns having elements not in order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets that look like this:

```
          name  Longitude   Latitude      continent
0        Aruba -69.982677  12.520880  North America
1  Afghanistan  66.004734  33.835231           Asia
2       Angola  17.537368 -12.293361         Africa
3     Anguilla -63.064989  18.223959  North America
4      Albania  20.049834  41.142450         Europe
```

And another dataset looks like this:

```
          COUNTRY  GDP (BILLIONS) CODE
0     Afghanistan           21.71  AFG
1         Albania           13.40  ALB
2         Algeria          227.80  DZA
3  American Samoa            0.75  ASM
4         Andorra            4.80  AND
```

Here, columns `name` and `COUNTRY` contains the country names but not in the same order.

How to combine the second dataframe into first one and add the `CODE` columns to the first dataframe.

Required output:

```
          name  Longitude   Latitude      continent   CODE
0        Aruba -69.982677  12.520880  North America   NaN
1  Afghanistan  66.004734  33.835231           Asia   AFG
2       Angola  17.537368 -12.293361         Africa   NaN
3     Anguilla -63.064989  18.223959  North America   NaN
4      Albania  20.049834  41.142450         Europe   ALB
```

Attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Aruba', 'Afghanistan', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Albania'],
          'Longitude' : [-69.982677, 66.004734, 17.537368, -63.064989, 20.049834],
          'Latitude' : [12.520880, 33.835231, '-12.293361', 18.223959, 41.142450],
          'continent' : ['North America','Asia','Africa','North America','Europe'] })
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY' :  ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American Samoa', 'Andorra'],
          'GDP (BILLIONS)' : [21.71, 13.40, 227.80, 0.75, 4.80],
          'CODE' : ['AFG', 'ALB', 'DZA', 'ASM', 'AND']})
print(df2)


pd.merge(left=df, right=df2,left_on='name',right_on='COUNTRY')
# but this fails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) uses `how='inner'`, which uses the **intersection** of keys across your two dataframes. Here, you need `how='left'` to use keys only from the `left` dataframe:

```
res = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='COUNTRY')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also completed the question, added code for df and df2. So that it maybe useful to others too.

Answer (score 1):

The merge performs an 'inner' merge or join by default, only keeping records that have a match on both the left and the right. You want an 'outer' join, keeping all records (there is also 'left' or 'right').

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Aruba', 'Afghanistan', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Albania'],
    'Longitude': [-69.982677, 66.004734, 17.537368, -63.064989, 20.049834],
    'Latitude': [12.520880, 33.835231, '-12.293361', 18.223959, 41.142450],
    'continent': ['North America', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'North America', 'Europe']
})
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'COUNTRY': ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American Samoa', 'Andorra'],
    'GDP (BILLIONS)': [21.71, 13.40, 227.80, 0.75, 4.80],
    'CODE': ['AFG', 'ALB', 'DZA', 'ASM', 'AND']
})
print(df2)

# merge, using 'outer' to avoid losing records from either left or right
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on='name', right_on='COUNTRY', how='outer')
# combining the columns used to match
df3['name'] = df3.apply(lambda row: row['name'] if not pd.isnull(row['name']) else row['COUNTRY'], axis=1)
# dropping the now spare column
df3 = df3.drop('COUNTRY', axis=1)
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas have pd.merge [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html] function which uses inner join by default. Inner join basically takes only those values that are present in both the keys specified in either `on` or on `left_on` and `right_on` if the keys to merge on in both the dataframes are different.

Since, you require the `CODE` value to be added, following line of code could be used:

`pd.merge(left=df, right=df2[['COUNTRY', 'CODE']], left_on='name', right_on='COUNTRY', how='left')`

This gives the following output:

```
          name  Longitude   Latitude      continent      COUNTRY CODE
0        Aruba -69.982677  12.520880  North America          NaN  NaN
1  Afghanistan  66.004734  33.835231           Asia  Afghanistan  AFG
2       Angola  17.537368 -12.293361         Africa          NaN  NaN
3     Anguilla -63.064989  18.223959  North America          NaN  NaN
4      Albania  20.049834  41.142450         Europe      Albania  ALB
```

Following also gives the same result:

`new_df = pd.merge(left=df1[['COUNTRY', 'CODE']], right=df, left_on='COUNTRY', right_on='name', how='right')`

```
       COUNTRY CODE         name  Longitude   Latitude      continent
0  Afghanistan  AFG  Afghanistan  66.004734  33.835231           Asia
1      Albania  ALB      Albania  20.049834  41.142450         Europe
2          NaN  NaN        Aruba -69.982677  12.520880  North America
3          NaN  NaN       Angola  17.537368 -12.293361         Africa
4          NaN  NaN     Anguilla -63.064989  18.223959  North America
```